# Accumulate Documents with Dynamic Keys

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents that look like this

```
{
   _id: 1,
   weight: 2,
   height: 3,
   fruit: "Orange",
   bald: "Yes"
},
{
   _id: 2,
   weight: 4,
   height: 5,
   fruit: "Apple",
   bald: "No"
}
```

I need to get a result that aggregates the entire collection into this.

```
{
   avgWeight: 3,
   avgHeight: 4,
   orangeCount: 1,
   appleCount: 1,
   baldCount: 1
}
```

I think I could map/reduce this, or I could query the averages and counts separately.  The only values fruit could ever have are Apple and Orange.  What other ways would you go about doing this?  I've been away from MongoDB for a while now and maybe there are new amazing ways to do this I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.demo.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $project: {
                weight: 1,
                height: 1,
                Orange: {
                    $cond: {
                        if: {
                            $eq: ["$fruit", 'Orange']
                        },
                        then: {
                            $sum: 1
                        },
                        else: 0
                    }
                },
                Apple: {
                    $cond: {
                        if: {
                            $eq: ["$fruit", 'Apple']
                        },
                        then: {
                            $sum: 1
                        },
                        else: 0
                    }
                },
                bald: {
                    $cond: {
                        if: {
                            $eq: ["$bald", 'Yes']
                        },
                        then: {
                            $sum: 1
                        },
                        else: 0
                    }
                },
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $group: {
                _id: null,
                avgWeight: {
                    $avg: '$weight'
                },
                avgHeight: {
                    $avg: '$height'
                },
                orangeCount: {
                    $sum: '$Orange'
                },
                appleCount: {
                    $sum: '$Apple'
                },
                baldCount: {
                    $sum: '$bald'
                }
            }
        },

    ]



);
```

Comment: So what happens when there's a watermelon? I think you missed the point of the question as the OP clearly does not know all the data or want to construct a condition for each possible value.

Comment: @NeilLunn I specifically said there would never be a watermelon.  I would try this out tonight after work, it looks like it will do exactly what I need.  I didn't even think to use a $project and $group to emulate map/reduce.  This looks promising.

Comment: @JoshuaLawrenceAustill Granted you did say that. However I would not recommend "hard coding" these even so as the conditional evaluation adds more overhead. There is also another case for the "one" valid usage with the `"bald"` data which I explain as well. Nonetheless `$project` is unecesesary here and adds even more overhead by transforming all the data before accumulating. That's really expensive, and can be done better as I also demonstrate.

Comment: This works perfectly, even allows me to create a view.

Answer (score 2):

## Aggregation Framework

The aggregation framework will do far better for you than what mapReduce can do, and the basic method is compatible with every release back to 2.2 when the aggregation framework was released.

If you have **MongoDB 3.6** you can do

```
db.fruit.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$fruit",
    "avgWeight": { "$avg": "$weight" },
    "avgHeight": { "$avg": "$height" },
    "baldCount": {
      "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$bald", "Yes"] }, 1, 0] }
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "data": {
      "$push": { 
         "k": { 
           "$concat": [
             { "$toLower": "$_id" },
             "Count"
           ]
         }, 
         "v": "$count"
      }
    },
    "avgWeight": { "$avg": "$avgWeight" },
    "avgHeight": { "$avg": "$avgHeight" },
    "baldCount": { "$sum": "$baldCount" }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$mergeObjects": [
        { "$arrayToObject": "$data" },
        {
          "avgWeight": "$avgWeight",
          "avgHeight": "$avgHeight",
          "baldCount": "$baldCount"
        }      
      ]
    }  
  }}
])
```

As a slight alternate, you can apply the [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) in the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) here instead:

```
db.fruit.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$fruit",
    "avgWeight": { "$avg": "$weight" },
    "avgHeight": { "$avg": "$height" },
    "baldCount": {
      "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$bald", "Yes"] }, 1, 0] }
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "data": {
      "$mergeObjects": {
        "$arrayToObject": [[{
          "k": { 
            "$concat": [
              { "$toLower": "$_id" },
              "Count"
            ]
          }, 
          "v": "$count"
        }]]
      }
    },
    "avgWeight": { "$avg": "$avgWeight" },
    "avgHeight": { "$avg": "$avgHeight" },
    "baldCount": { "$sum": "$baldCount" }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$mergeObjects": [
        "$data",
        {
          "avgWeight": "$avgWeight",
          "avgHeight": "$avgHeight",
          "baldCount": "$baldCount"
        }      
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

But there are reasons why I personally don't think that is the better approach, and that mostly leads to the next concept.

So even if you don't have a "latest" MongoDB release, you can simply reshape the output since that is all the last pipeline stage actually using the MongoDB 3.6 features is doing:

```
db.fruit.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$fruit",
    "avgWeight": { "$avg": "$weight" },
    "avgHeight": { "$avg": "$height" },
    "baldCount": {
      "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$bald", "Yes"] }, 1, 0] }
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "data": {
      "$push": { 
         "k": { 
           "$concat": [
             { "$toLower": "$_id" },
             "Count"
           ]
         }, 
         "v": "$count"
      }
    },
    "avgWeight": { "$avg": "$avgWeight" },
    "avgHeight": { "$avg": "$avgHeight" },
    "baldCount": { "$sum": "$baldCount" }
  }},
  /*
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$mergeObjects": [
        { "$arrayToObject": "$data" },
        {
          "avgWeight": "$avgWeight",
          "avgHeight": "$avgHeight",
          "baldCount": "$baldCount"
        }      
      ]
    }  
  }}
  */
]).map( d =>
  Object.assign(
    d.data.reduce((acc,curr) => Object.assign(acc,{ [curr.k]: curr.v }), {}),
    { avgWeight: d.avgWeight, avgHeight: d.avgHeight, baldCount: d.baldCount }
  )
)
```

And of course you can even just "hardcode" the keys:

```
db.fruit.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "appleCount": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$fruit", "Apple"] }, 1, 0]
      }
    },
    "orangeCount": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$fruit", "Orange"] }, 1, 0]
      }
    },
    "avgWeight": { "$avg": "$weight" },
    "avgHeight": { "$avg": "$height" },
    "baldCount": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$bald", "Yes"] }, 1, 0]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

But it would not be recommended as your data might just change some day, and if there is a value to "group on" then it's better to actually use it than coercing with conditions.

In any form you return the same result:

```
{
        "appleCount" : 1,
        "orangeCount" : 1,
        "avgWeight" : 3,
        "avgHeight" : 4,
        "baldCount" : 1
}
```

We do this with "two" [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stages, being once for accumulating "per fruit" and then secondly to compact all fruit to an array using [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) under `"k"` and `"v"` values to keep their "key" and their "count". We do a little transformation on the "key" here using [`$toLower`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLower/) and [`$concat`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) to join the strings. This is optional at this stage but easier in general.

The "alternate" for 3.6 is simply applying [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) within this earlier stage instead of [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) since we already accumulated these keys. It's just really moving the [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) to a different stage in the pipeline. It's not really necessary and does not really have any specific advantage. If anything it just removes the flexible option as demonstrated with the "client transform" discussed later.

The "average" accumulations are done via [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) and the `"bald"` is counted using [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to test the strings and feed a number to [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/). As the array is "rolled up" we can do all those accumulations again to total for everything.

As mentioned, the only part that actually relies on "new features" is all within the [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) stage which re-writes the "root" document. That's why this is optional as you can simply do these transformations after the same "already aggregated" data is returned from the database.

All we really do here is take that array with the `"k"` and `"v"` entries and turn it into an "object" with named keys via [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) and apply [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) on that result with the other keys we already produced at the "root". This transforms that array to be part of the main document returned in result.

The exact same transformation is applied using the JavaScript [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) methods in the `mongo` shell compatible code. It's a very simple thing to apply and the `Cursor.map()` is generally a feature of most language implementations, so you can do these transforms before you start using the cursor results.

With ES6 compatible JavaScript environments ( not the shell ), we can shorten that syntax a little more:

```
.map(({ data, ...d }) => ({ ...data.reduce((o,[k,v]) => ({ ...o, [k]: v }), {}), ...d }) )
```

So it truly is a "one line" function, and that's a general reason why transformations like these are often better in the client code than the server anyway.

As a note on the usage of [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), it is noted that using it for "hardcoded" evaluation is not really a good idea for several reasons. So it really does not make much sense to "force" that evaluation. Even with the data you present the `"bald"` would be better expressed as a `Boolean` value than a "string". If you change `"Yes/No"` to be `true/false` then even that "one" valid usage becomes:

```
"baldCount": { "$sum": { "$cond": ["$bald", 1, 0 ] } }
```

Which removes the need to "test" a condition on a string match since it's already `true/false`. MongoDB 4.0 adds another enhancement using [`$toInt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/) to "coerce" the `Boolean` to an integer:

```
"baldCount": { "$sum": { "$toInt": "$bald" } }
```

That removes the need for [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) altogether, as would simply recording `1` or `0` but that change might cause a loss of clarity in the data, so it is still probably reasonable to have that sort of "coercion" there, but not really optimal anywhere else.

Even with the "dynamic" form using "two" [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stages for accumulation, the main work is still done in the first stage. It simply leaves the remaining accumulation on `n` result documents for the number of possible unique values of the grouping key. In this case "two", so even though it's an additional instruction there is no real overhead for the gain of having flexible code.

---

## MapReduce

If you really have you're heart set on at least "trying" a `mapReduce`, then it's really a single pass with a `finalize` function just to make the averages

```
db.fruit.mapReduce(
  function() {
    emit(null,{ 
      "key": { [`${this.fruit.toLowerCase()}Count`]: 1 },
      "totalWeight": this.weight,
      "totalHeight": this.height,
      "totalCount": 1,
      "baldCount": (this.bald === "Yes") ? 1 : 0
    });
  },
  function(key,values) {
    var output = {
      key: { },
      totalWeight: 0,
      totalHeight: 0,
      totalCount: 0,
      baldCount: 0
    };

    for ( let value of values ) {
      for ( let key in value.key ) {
        if ( !output.key.hasOwnProperty(key) )
          output.key[key] = 0;

        output.key[key] += value.key[key];
      }

      Object.keys(value).filter(k => k != 'key').forEach(k =>
        output[k] += value[k]
      )
    }

    return output;
  },
  { 
    "out": { "inline": 1 },
    "finalize": function(key,value) {
      return Object.assign(
        value.key,
        {
          avgWeight: value.totalWeight / value.totalCount,
          avgHeight: value.totalHeight / value.totalCount,
          baldCount: value.baldCount
        }
      )
    }
  }
)
```

Since we already ran through the process for the `aggregate()` method then the general points should be pretty familiar since we are basically doing much the same thing here.

The main differences are for an "average" you actually need the full totals and counts and of course you get a bit more control over accumulating via an "Object" with JavaScript code.

The results are basically the same, just with the standard `mapReduce` "bent" on how it presents them:

```
  {
      "_id" : null,
      "value" : {
        "orangeCount" : 1,
        "appleCount" : 1,
        "avgWeight" : 3,
        "avgHeight" : 4,
        "baldCount" : 1
      }
  }
```

## Summary

The general catch being of course that MapReduce using interpreted JavaScript in order to execute has a much higher cost and slower execution than the native coded operations of the aggregation framework.There once may have been an option to use MapReduce for this kind of output on "larger" result sets, but since MongoDB 2.6 introduced "cursor" output for the aggregation framework then the scales have been firmly tipped in favor of the newer option.

Fact is that most "legacy" reasons for employing MapReduce is basically superseded by it's younger sibling as the aggregation framework gains new operations which remove the need for the JavaScript execution environment. It would be a fair comment to say that support for JavaScript execution is generally "dwindling", and once legacy options which used this from the beginning are being gradually removed from the product.